# How can I achieve the same behavior as NavigateUp when performing a back action?

Tags: android

My current basic structure is as follows, and I'm not sure if it's correct:
I have a MainActivity, which I use to maintain a NavHostFragment in the layout.

Aside from that, I have two fragments, MainFragment and SearchFragment. The first one will display the main page content, and the second is for displaying search results.

I use the NavHostFragment to load MainFragment at the start of navigation.

[image]

Additionally, the layout of MainActivity is wrapped inside a DrawerLayout, which has an ActionBar. This ActionBar contains a search item displaying a search icon.

When I press that icon, two things happen: on one hand, a SearchView opens in the bar, and on the other, it navigates to the SearchFragment.

Up to this point, all is well.

The **problem **comes when returning to the MainFragment because:

If I **return using the action bar's arrow**, which internally uses NavigateUp(), it works perfectly. I return in just two taps.

On the first tap on the arrow, the keyboard closes, and the SearchView collapses at once, displaying the SearchFragment's name in the bar. On the second tap, it navigates back. This is correct and what I want.

If I **return using the back gesture**, in my case, it's done by dragging from a side edge of the screen inward. In this case, the behavior changes, and it requires 3 back actions to reach the MainFragment.
On the first tap, the keyboard closes; on the second tap, the SearchView collapses; and on the third tap, it navigates from the SearchFragment to the MainFragment.

I have tried many things, like overriding onBackPressed() from MainActivity, which manages all of this. Adding a onBackPressedDispatcher callback. Setting it in onCreateOptionsMenu. But a curious phenomenon occurs: the condition !viewSearch.isIconified is never met because someone consumes the back press before it gets there, but it does reach isIconified. I am lost at this point.

I have made two videos, one showing the desired behavior and the other the behavior I have.

Good:[expected behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KJER866wEM)
Bad: [observed behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88Urf4v9jkk)